# Is ES6 `export class A` equivalent to `module.exports = A`?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

When I see the compiled code by Babel, they do not seem to be equivalent.
Actually, the former transforms to `exports.A = A`, which is not equivalent to `module.exports = A` (Maybe it is `module.exports.A = A`?)

So is there an ES6 style `module.export =`? Or the syntax remains still in ES6? Or that syntax is no more recommended in ES6?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use

```
export default class A {

}
```

Or

```
class A {

}

export default A;
```

Which will export as

```
exports["default"] = A;
module.exports = exports["default"];
```

There's an explanation why in the interop section [here.](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/#interop)

> In order to encourage the use of CommonJS and ES6 modules, when exporting a default export with no other exports `module.exports` will be set in addition to `exports["default"]`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following in **Node v6:**

```
"use strict" 

class ClassName {
 // class code
}

module.exports = ClassName
```

Save the above file as **ClassName.js** 
 
To import it in another file Test.js:

```
"use strict"
var ClassName= require('./ClassName.js');
var obj = new ClassName( Vars . . . );
```

For more Info:

[Here's an article on exporting classes from modules in Node v6](https://rishabh.io/recipes/how-to-export-a-class-from-module-nodejs6.html)

Answer (score 2):

babel6 is not supported `export default A` to `modules.export=A`

you should add a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports)